# Flutter Real Mobile App Problem: Stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

When I built my flutter android app, it opened perfectly in the simulator on my emulator. When I publish the app, the app does not work anymore. The splashscreen is shown, but stays on the screen.

(Even after flutter clean )

Comment: Hi, by 'publishing the app' do you mean deploying it on a physical device?

Comment: Logs are going to be your friend here, they'll tell you what's going on. If you're on android, open Android Studio and look for the LogCat part of the window. On iOS, you can use the command line tool `idevicesyslog | grep Runner`

Comment: yes @JosefBüttgen,    it worked on emulator but not running in some real physical devices.